# SapUi5 TreeTable is different rendered within jQuery.getJSON() call

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I create several treetables, each is placed on it's own div.
The main reproducable problem i've got:

- creating the tables directly -> everything looks fine (see image 1)
- creating the tables within an asynchron jQuery call: the first added table gets always a vertical scrollbar (see image 2)

here is the code:

```
var oData = { root: ...}

// code for image 2
jQuery.getJSON(url, function (result) {
   createTable(oData['table1'], 'table1')
   createTable(oData['table2'], 'table2')
})

// code for image 1
createTable(oData['table1'], 'table1') 
createTable(oData['table2'], 'table2')

function createTable(oData, codeSample){
  var oTable = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable({
    columns: [
      new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "trans_class", template: "trans_class"})
      , new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Checked", template: "checked"})
    ],
      height: '100%',
      selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None,
      enableColumnReordering: false,
      expandFirstLevel: false,
      visibleRowCount : INITIAL_ROW_COUNT_IN_TABLE,
      visibleRowCountMode : sap.ui.table.VisibleRowCountMode.Auto,
      toggleOpenState: function(oEvent) {
        var isLeafExpanded = oEvent.getParameter("expanded");
        if(isLeafExpanded){
          oTable.setVisibleRowCount(oTable.getVisibleRowCount() + 2)
          SUM_INDEX_TOGGLE = SUM_INDEX_TOGGLE + 2
        }else{
          oTable.setVisibleRowCount(oTable.getVisibleRowCount() - 2)
          SUM_INDEX_TOGGLE = SUM_INDEX_TOGGLE - 2
        }
      }
    })

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(oData);
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, codeSample);
    oTable.bindRows("/root");
    oTable.expand(4); // expand Sum Row

    //Bring the table onto the UI
    oTable.placeAt(codeSample);
```

}

How can I fix this issue. I want that all my tables look the same.
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: add a simple textField and hide it after adding the treeTable:

```
addSimpleHiddenTextField(HIDDEN_TEXTFIELD)
for(var i in config.TABLES){
  createTableAndPlaceIt(result[i], i, config.TABLES[i])
}
hideSimpleTextField(HIDDEN_TEXTFIELD)
```